# Can't create module block in the template in Marketo

Tags: html, email, marketo

I can't create custom mpdule in my template in Marketo. I read this https://docs.marketo.com/display/public/DOCS/Email+Template+Syntax .

I added mktoname, class and id: class="mktoModule" mktoname="Text" id="txt1" in the table. But cant save html, it's error in id="txt1"
I can't understand what's wrong. Can you help me?

I can create dynamic blocks in Marketo, but can't create modules.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full email template, this is going to be hard to diagnose, but some things you can look at to help deduce what might be the problem include:

- Do extensive tag closure checks. The most common reason a module will fail is that it isn't properly closed in some way with a stray missing `</td>` tag or what have you. You can use an HTML linter for this, but a site like [HTML Tidy Online](https://infohound.net/tidy/) or [Closing Tag Checker](https://www.aliciaramirez.com/closing-tags-checker/) can work in a pinch.
- Ensure your module setup works with your container setup. Every module *must* be within your `.mktoContainer` parent and all of your module children must be at the same hierarchy level--so if your container is a `<table>`, the modules all must be immediate `<td>` children; if your container is a `<td>`, they all should be `<table>` children, and so on.
- Try pulling your modules one-by-one from your code to see where there may be issues, then re-introduce them once they've been known to work.